# Model.save() and ModelForm.save() works together

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am new to django. I want to know how ModelForm and Model in django works together ? I mean how ModelForm.save() automatically saves model associated with it ? How does it create model from request.POST information ?

Please explain me with the help of example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method:

> Every ModelForm also has a save() method. This method creates and saves a database object from the data bound to the form.

There are also examples on the page.

Answer (score 1):

One of the nice things with open source software is that you don't have to ask how it works since you can just read the code: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py